# Could not initialize class com.sample.PMF (Google app engine)

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, persistence-manager

I am getting this error while trying to save something to Datastore.
I have tried to search but not getting anything.
This is the code where i am saving to datastore :

```
    Student temp = null;
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        Student stu = new Student(name);
        temp = pm.makePersistent(stu);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return temp;
```

Any kind of information on this is appreciated!

**EDIT**: adding stack trace :

at com.sample.dbops.DBManager.saveStudent(DBManager.java:18)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:251)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:124)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful

Comment: Added... the class DBManager is having this static saveStudent method... its the first line in my jsp and i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace did not help much, but one reason for not initializing the PersistenceManagerFactory is that it could not find a persistence unit that you specified in the `JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(String)` method.

e.g. If your PMF's `get()` method looks like this:

```
public static synchronized PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
    if(pmfInstance == null)  {
        pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(
              "transactions-optional");
    }
    return pmfInstance;
}
```

Then you must have a jdoconfig.xml in your classpath (e.g. WEB-INF/classes) that defines a persistence unit as follows: (with same name that you used in getPersistenceManagerFactory). In this case "transactions-optional"

```
    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="false"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
```

Comment: Is jdoconfig.xml in your classpath?

Comment: I have tried the greeting example from google, and it worked! but my my project is giving this error... one quick question : my saveStudent(name) method is static : does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Solved : I was calling the above code from a static method, now i made it an instance method and it worked.
but still confused?